# Packt sie euch!

Tags: meaning, pronoun

Ich habe Folgendes im Roman *Mieses Karma* von David Safier gelesen:

> «Packt sie euch!», schrie die Königin, und ich sah, dass die Wachen
> uns schon so gut wie erreicht hatten.

Ich würde hier einfach «Packt sie!» erwarten, um diesen Befehl der Königin zu äußern. Was fügt hier das Wort *euch* hinzu? Die reflexive Version des Verbes, also *sich* packen, hat offenbar eine beziehungslose Bedeutung, die in diesem Zusammenhang keinen Sinn machen würde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das ist sehr wahrscheinlich ganz einfach ein Fehler oder eine Verwechslung mit "sich schnappen"

Beide Verben können reflexiv verwendet werden, haben dann allerdings eine andere Grundbedeutung:

*sich schnappen* wird umgangssprachlich im Sinne von "jemand oder etwas zu fassen bekommen, ergreifen, festnehmen" verwendet.

*sich packen* wird umgangssprachlich als "sich fortscheren" - eigentlich: "sich bepacken und abhauen" verwendet (meistens im Imperativ, "Pack dich" heißt ganz einfach "hau ab!"). Aber niemals reflexiv als "ergreift ihn".

Comment: @HalvarF Tja, Mist. Falscher Sprachchip gesteckt.

Comment: https://www.deutschmeisterei.de/26890-2/ Vielleicht hat der Verfasser "Mieses Karma" gelesen? Aber im Ernst, Google liefert zahlreiche Treffer. Möglicherweise ein regionales Ding?